# A PHP script that receives POST information from a form, takes them, adds to them, and passes them on

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, post

A fairly basic question, I'm looking to know which is the proper way of doing it.

I can create an html form where the user can put his/her input and then passes them `(action=http://...)` into a php script.

I can create a php script that receives these data and stores them as variables:

```
..
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
..
```

Now, I wanna take these variables (plus some more pre-defined in this very script) and automatically "post" these fields into different address that would further handle them. (by "post", I mean the exact same way the html form "posted" these fields into this script to begin with)

To make it a little clearer: this problem wouldn't exist if I were to include all the need values as hidden fields in the script and asked the user to click "submit", I'm basically looking for a way to make the typical (html => form => fields => Post) happen automatically.

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: why not just post them to the further address in the first place? secondly you CAN use hidden form fields to carry information if you need to

Comment: @SamCreamer you can use hidden fields, but if the information is sensitive (i.e. you don't want the user to be able to see the values if they do a view-source) hidden fields aren't really a security measure. Not saying that's the OP's issue; just that it's something to consider.

Comment: @EmmyS good point, not sure what the OP needs security wise

Comment: Session variables may be the solution here. Store variables that you need to persist in a `$_SESSION` variable and access them when you need them.

Comment: Thank-you for all your answers, @EmmyS has hit it spot on, I have specific variables that I wouldn't want visible to the public (the pre-defined ones mentioned), I need to process them PLUS the info originally obtained in the html form and send them as are. Regarding Session variables, I haven't really worked with them before, If anyone thinks they achieve the security purpose of hiding some sensitive variables as well as help me do the automatic "passing on/ posting to a further address", I could read into it.

Comment: still sounds like you only need to post once, and you can store those values in that PHP script if they are hardcoded, as well as pass the ones from the form to php thru your html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store them in a session and access them later. That way the user isn't able to see the values, like they would if you used hidden fields.

Declare them like this:

```
<?php

session_start(); //START THE SESSION

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

?>
```

Then whenever you want to access them, on any script, use `$_SESSION['name']` or `$_SESSION['email']`. BUT you always have to declare `session_start();` on every page/script you want to access them on.

Read up on PHP sessions here: [The PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think sessions maybe what I need, although I don't really get why you'd need cookies in this situation.. All I wanna do is collect simple user information (product id.. etc), process them along some sensetive variables (merchant's secure-key..etc) and "Post" it all in a specific way to to some payment processor's address. Now I'm assuming I have to set the sensitive variables as session variables in the beginning of my script (simply makes them better hidden than the html "hidden field" way), and call these variables when needed. Correct?

Comment: Also how can I take the information just posted using the form and turn it into a variable for further manipulation, all within one script .php file?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was working on another question when I got PHP cookies. I corrected the link to go to the PHP sessions section. To turn the info just posted from a form in one script, declare a variable that is equal to `$_POST['name']`. Like this: `$name = $_POST['name'];`. This is advised against though because it is just more lines of code.

Comment: No Problem! Quick question, does the session solution up there still apply when using a single script to retrieve and turn info into variables?

Comment: If you are only using a single script to process data that JUST came from a form, use the `$_POST['']` variables. If you are using a script to process and use data that didn't just come from a form and you have the info in session variables, use them. Also, if I helped you click the upward arrow next to my answer. If I solved your question click the checkmark next to my answer.